# Не работает margin: ...;

Tags: html, css

Всем привет, я пробывл и щас конечно пытаюсь понять в чем проблема, но у меня не работает стиль css `margin` в таблице.

Мне надо чтоб один объект в таблице переместить вниз на 10px, но он не чего не перемещает пробывал сделать

```
margin-top: 10px;
```

и добавлял после того как не получилось

```
display: block;
```

все равно не работает, подскажите как правильно сделать. 
Весь код:

```
<style>
.beatbox-margin {
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: block;
}
</style>
<table width="60%" bgcolor="#FFFFFF" align="center" style="
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;">
  <tr>
    <td width="37%" align="center"><?php 
    print <<<HERE
    <img alt='Рейпер $_SESSION[login]' class='avatar' src='accounts/$myrow[avatar]'><br />
    $_SESSION[login]
HERE;
    ?></td>
    <td width="23%" align="center" class="beatbox-margin">
    <?php 
    print <<<HERE
    <img alt="Бит бокс от $_SESSION[login]" height="100" width="100" class="avatar" src="accounts/$myrow[avatar]"><br />
    $_SESSION[login]
HERE;
    ?>
    </td>
    <td width="40%" align="center">
    <?php 
    print <<<HERE
    <img alt="Рейпер $_SESSION[login]" height="100" width="100" class="avatar" src="accounts/$myrow[avatar]"><br />
    $_SESSION[login]
HERE;
    ?>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

работает ведь http://jsfiddle.net/88QJq/

Comment: Странно, а до этого не работало) Спасибо, хотя не за что, но все равно ;)

Comment: Только щас одна проблема, не выравнивается по цнтру с помощью html-тег (<center></center> <table align="center"></table>). Или надо тоже через css выравнивать?

Comment: Саша, http://jsfiddle.net/88QJq/1/